# jquery mousemove transform both x and y of 3d shape

Tags: jquery, css, mousemove

I want to make the 3d element rotate in both x and y axis based on the position of the mouse on the screen. I have successfully made this happen on X position OR Y positions but are unable to make it work on both positions at once.

My code:

```
var $document = $(document);

$document.mousemove(function(e) {
    var height = $document.height() / 60;
    var pageY = e.pageY / height;
    var valueY = 180 - pageY;

    $(".cube").css("transform", "rotateZ(" + valueY + "deg)");    
});

$document.mousemove(function(e) {
    var width = $document.width() / 40;
    var pageX = e.pageX / width;
    var valueX = 125 - pageX;

    $(".cube").css("transform", "rotateY(" + valueX + "deg)");
});
```

There is a codepen:
https://codepen.io/asmundsol/pen/PRXZRa

Comment: combine both function ...https://jsfiddle.net/0ry5cq3h/

Comment: Could you help me do that? @TemaniAfif

Comment: Amazing. Thank you @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 0):

```
var $document = $(document);

$document.mousemove(function(e) {
    var height = $document.height() / 60;
    var pageY = e.pageY / height;
    var valueY = 180 - pageY;
        var width = $document.width() / 40;
    var pageX = e.pageX / width;
    var valueX = 125 - pageX;

    $(".cube").css("transform", "rotateZ(" + valueY + "deg) rotateY(" + valueX + "deg)");    
});
```